# How to implement and instance of Show manually?

Tags: haskell

I am learning to use typeclasses in haskell.

The following code works.

```
data Mood = Blah | Woot deriving (Show)
changeMood :: Mood -> Mood
changeMood Blah = Woot
changeMood Woot = Blah

main = do
    print (changeMood Blah)
    print (changeMood Woot)
```

But the following gives error `error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Mood’`.

```
data Mood = Blah | Woot
changeMood :: Mood -> Mood
changeMood Blah = Woot
changeMood Woot = Blah

instance Show Mood where
    show(Mood x) = "Mood: " ++ show(x)

main = do
    print (changeMood Blah)
    print (changeMood Woot)
```

How can I make the second code work (implement `show` function).

Comment: Would it help you if I told you that `show (Mood x)` doesn't work because `Mood` is a type and not a data constructor? The data constructors you have define `show` rules for are `Blah` and `Woot`.

Comment: Note that it isn't good practice to add the `"Mood: "` prefix in a custom Show instance (they should match the derived instances were possible). Instead you could add it where you do the printing: `putStrLn $ "Mood: " ++ show (changeMood Blah)`. Of course it is fine to do this as an exercise while learning about type classes.

Comment: A thought experiment: suppose this *did* work. What implementation of `show` is being used when you write `show(x)`? What entity created the code of that implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mood` is a type, not a value. It can be used only in type signatures, after `::`, and in constraints (as in `instance Show Mood`).

The values are `Blah` and `Woot`, so use those:

```
instance Show Mood where
    show Blah = "Mood: Blah"
    show Woot = "Mood: Woot"
```

Comment: If it has to be something along those lines I'd make it `"(Blah :: Mood)"` and `"(Woot :: Mood)"`, so it's actually valid Haskell syntax. But more likely it would of course be better to just not define the instance manually at all, but derive it instead, in which case the results will be just `"Blah"` and `"Woot"` – which is quite sufficient too.